# Does performing and ArrayList.clear() also mark held resources for garbage collection?

Tags: android, arraylist, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have an ArrayList of Bitmaps which change through each iteration of a for loop. When I call

```
ArrayList.clear()
```

Should I need to make a call to

```
ArrayList.get(i).recycle()
```

to purge these resources, or will they be marked for regular garbage collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said, `ArrayList.clear()` will set all the items inside elegible for the garbage collector but not the reference of the list itself.

For example, if you had a list of 40 items and then made `list.clear()` this will set the 40 items elegible for the **GC** but you will have a reference to a list with a size in memory for 40 items.

If you want **GC** taking care of your list too, you just have to do `list = null;`

Hope it helped to clarify what you asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayList.clear() method implicitly sets its all elements to null which makes them eligible for garbage collection. It will have some thing like this

```
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
       elementData[i] = null;
    }
```

Arraylist internally stores your objects in an array.

Comment: While this does answer the question, axierjhtjz provided a more detailed answer.

Comment: Also, with arraylist, correct syntax of your code would be "ArrayList.set(i, null);"

Comment: hmm yeah if you want to take pain of doing it by yourselves.